# boostrap col-offset not working inside row-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am having fluid design, where i want to get form group elements inside the row-fluid with one condition, i have to align the form group elements on right side.

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="background-color: #332619; color: #fff !important; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 10px">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_Email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login_Password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1pzh4x8s/

but in my html page form-group elements are not wrapped inside row-fluid div.image below

[image]

Comment: bootstrap is not included in the fiddle O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, AFAIK there is no such thing as `row-fluid`. You need to use `container-fluid` and then `row` inside.

Secondly, what is the point of having `col-lg-12` in the row and then immediately inside `col-6`. The `col-lg-12` serves no purpose.

Additionally, your elements are wrapped in the markup, but not visually. You need to add `clearfix` to the parent in order for it's height to extend to the height of the last/tallest floated child.